# Proper way to update a Document with mongocsharpdriver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

i'm creating a simple document manager for a dummy Project

for now i have **Insert** and **Update** methods

```
public ObjectId Insert(T model)
{

    _collection.Insert(model);

    return model.Id;
}

public void Update(T model)
{
    var query = Query.EQ("_id", model.Id);

    var bson = model.ToBsonDocument();
    bson.Remove("_id");

    var update = new UpdateDocument
    {
        { "$set" , bson }
    };
    _collection.Update(query, update);
}
```

this is a proper way to doing this?. I'm newbie with mongo and mongocsharpdriver. i'm having problems saving properties like List<>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to save a document back to the database is to use the Save method:

```
collection.Save(model);
```

This does result in the entire document being sent to the server, so if you know that only a few fields are changing you can use Update.Set to change just those fields.

See online documentation at:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-Save%3CTDocument%3Emethod

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-Updatemethod